# Merworthy behavior on php DateTime-format() - results with different timezone

Tags: php, datetime, format, timezone

I have a strange problem by formatting php DateTime-Object in relation to the (same) timezone.

It looks like the results have different timezones in different years.

In the following example I use '1944-06-09' and adding every time one year at the for-loop and formatting the date by RFC3339 to the Berlin timezone.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

$birth_date_string = '1944-06-09';  // YYYY-MM-DD
$birth_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', $birth_date_string);



for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    print_r('________________________________________________');
    $birth_date->modify('+1 years');
    var_dump($birth_date);

    $birth_date_formatted = $birth_date->format(\DateTime::RFC3339);
    var_dump($birth_date_formatted);
}
```

The output in some years has "+03:00", some years has "+02:00" and sometimes "+01:00"... all in timezone 'Europe/Berlin'.

```
________________________________________________
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:13:
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '1945-06-09 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:16:string '1945-06-09T00:00:00+03:00' (length=25)
________________________________________________
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:13:
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '1946-06-09 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:16:string '1946-06-09T00:00:00+02:00' (length=25)
________________________________________________
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:13:
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '1947-06-09 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:16:string '1947-06-09T00:00:00+03:00' (length=25)
________________________________________________
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:13:
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '1948-06-09 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:16:string '1948-06-09T00:00:00+02:00' (length=25)
________________________________________________
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:13:
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '1949-06-09 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:16:string '1949-06-09T00:00:00+02:00' (length=25)
________________________________________________
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:13:
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '1950-06-09 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:16:string '1950-06-09T00:00:00+01:00' (length=25)
________________________________________________
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:13:
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '1951-06-09 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:16:string '1951-06-09T00:00:00+01:00' (length=25)
________________________________________________
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:13:
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '1952-06-09 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:16:string '1952-06-09T00:00:00+01:00' (length=25)
________________________________________________
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:13:
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '1953-06-09 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
/vagrant/tests/test2.php:16:string '1953-06-09T00:00:00+01:00' (length=25)
```

tested on PHP ~7.4

No idea what could be the reason.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

That simply *was* the actual offset at those times.

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin?year=1945 says they were using CEMT back then.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Midsummer_Time:

> Central European Midsummer Time (CEMT) was a time zone three hours ahead of GMT, used as a double summer time in several European countries during the 1940s.